# Android App is incompatible on a lot of devices

Tags: android, incompatibility

I am the developer of a rather popular game published on Android Play Store. Until just the latest version, most devices, if not all, were able to download and enjoy this game. However with this latest version, a lot of older devices (~2 years old?) have started seeing the game as "incompatible" with their device.

I `diff`ed the manifest files of the two versions, and the only difference that pops up is the change to `android:versionName`, `android:versionCode`.

I related thread suggested that this might be because the APK might be too big for the devices. While it is true that we do have the APK sitting at ~49 mb, it only grew from 48.66 -> 48.68 this version, so I find it hard to believe that this is the reason.

The list of incompatible devices is quite extensive but here are some of the standouts..

> galaxy nexus
>   samsung galaxy tab 10.1 
>   Samsung Galaxy Tab 7.7
>   eeepad asus transformer tf101
>   Motorola XOOM
>   Acer Iconia Tab A700

This list is directly from our (former?) customers, but I have verified this on a Galaxy tab 10.1, and Transformer. Tab 2 and Nexus 7 are able to see it, if that helps.

**Update:** These devices are shown as compatible in the developer console.

Have there been any recent changes in the way these things are decided? Is there any service which tells us why the app is said to be incompatible?

The permissions section of my app is below

```
<permission android:name="com.nubee.japanlife.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.nubee.japanlife.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="7"/>
```

Comment: Share your manifest permissions section...

Comment: @PankajKumar I have added the permissions you asked for. The reason I didn't share it earlier is because the problem arose only in the latest version, and as I mentioned, there was no change in permissions in the last version.

Comment: Permissions are correct... you should change `android:targetSdkVersion="7"` to ICS or JellyBean

Comment: @PankajKumar yes I have been considering that, if only to get rid of the menu virtual button in new devices.. but have been wary of possible issues.. but that should not cause this right?

Comment: No no.. these must not cause any issue..

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you have lots of permissions in your application which in most devices / tablets won't let you to install it via Play Store. Depending on what is actually doing your application and in what kind of device (phone / tablet) it will be used in most cases you should consider using for example :

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
```

First of all it's just an example! I am doing that in one of my apps where I am letting the user call certain numbers, that's why I need `TELEPHONY` permission, but it's not neccessary for my app. That's why I am using `use_feature` with `required=false`.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Hi, I understand this, I will do these in the upcoming version, but since some tablets can still use this, and those that could not were still able to in the last version, is it likely that this will fix it?

Comment: I had a situation with a few tablets, where I can install apps on some by using usb storage, but if I try using Play Store it won't let me, but in some other tablets I can install app from both (usb/store). So in my opinion it depends on the device, because some tablets have ability to make calls and etc. But as far as I know and as far as I tested during my development life, this trick with `use-feature` made my app available for more devices. You can test it, create a new apk with the changed manifest, upload it, but do not publish it and I think you will be able to see supported devices.

Comment: There you have mentioned my main concern, a point which I perhaps should have mentioned.. The devices above are currently listed as compatible in the Developer console.

Comment: As I know, most of them have capabilities for telephony/sms/mms right. The point which I think you must consider here is what exactly is doing your app and if the user will be able to use it properly without these permissions.